# Is there any way to cancel background noise from being recorded into my microphone? Globally?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

On Windows I used to take advantage of acoustic echo cancellation and noise suppression but no such features exist in PulseAudio and haven't since I can remember. My system is a laptop, Acer Aspire V3-571G and you can guess it ran Realtek drivers as usual.

Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10, 12.10, I don't mind which version a fix applies too, as long as it's one of those three.

Comment: for echo cancelling see: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index44h3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Echo cancellation in Ubuntu [can be done](http://arunraghavan.net/2011/08/hello-hello-hello/) by running:

```
pactl load-module module-echo-cancel
```